# Using an array in GLSL shaders in WebGL

Tags: arrays, textures, opengl-es-2.0, glsl, webgl

So I'm trying to send an array of values to my fragment shader- 
The shader reads values from a texture and depending on the value currently being read by the texture, I want to retrieve a value from the array-

I am able to cast the value (u.r) to an int using int(u.r), but when I actually put that into the array index to find the value, it says that the integer isn't a constant, so I can't use it...

- ERROR: 0:75: '[]' : Index expression must be constant -

Is there a better way of sending arrays of values to the shader?

Here is some of the code- as you can see, the array "tab" is what I'm looking at mostly

```
    <script id="shader-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">


#ifdef GL_ES

precision highp float;

#endif

  uniform sampler2D uTexSamp;

uniform sampler2D uTabSamp;
  uniform float dt;
  uniform float dte;
  uniform float dth2;
  uniform float a;
  uniform float nb;
  uniform float m;
  uniform float eps;
    uniform float weee;

 uniform float tab[100];


    //uniform float temp;

  uniform int fframes;
  uniform vec2 vStimCoord;
  varying vec2 vTexCoord;

  const float d = 0.001953125; // 1./512.

void main(void) {

   vec4 t = texture2D(uTexSamp, vTexCoord);
   float u = t.r,  v = t.g,  u2 = t.b,  v2 = t.a;


    //const mediump int arrindex = floor(u*10 + u2);
    //float sigvaluetab = tab[arrindex];

    u += u2/255.;   v += v2/255.;

   //u += u2 * 0.003921568627451;
   v += v2 * 0.003921568627451;

   //Scaling factors
   v = v*1.2;
   u = u*4.;


   float temp =  (1.0 / (exp(2.0 * (u-3.0)) + 1.0)); // (1-tanh(u-3)) * 0.5



    //const mediump int utoint;
    //utoint = int(u);
    //for(int index = 0; index< 50; index++)

    int u2toint;
    u2toint = int(u2);

  //  int arrindex = utoint*10 + u2toint;
    float sigmoid = tab[u2toint];//(tab[5] + 1.);
    //float sigmoid= temp;//tab[arrindex];

   float hfunc   = sigmoid * u * u;
   float ffunc   = -u +(a - pow(v*nb,m))*hfunc ;

   float gfunc = -v;
   if (u  > 1.0) {   //u-1.0 > 0.0
       gfunc += 1.4990;
   }
```

... MORE STUFF UNDER, BUT THIS IS THE IDEA

Comment: I feel obligated to point out that `highp` is not required by the OpenGL ES 2.0 specification to work in a fragment shader. For compliance, you need to test the pre-processor define `GL_FRAGMENT_PRECISION_HIGH` before using `highp` in a fragment shader; it will be **1** if the implementation supports it, **undefined** otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

Fragment shaders are tricky, unlike vertex shaders where you can index a uniform using any integer expression in a fragment shader the expression must qualify as `const-index`. This can go as far as to rule out indexing uniforms in a loop in fragment shaders :-\

#### [GLSL ES Specification (version 100)](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/2.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_1.0.17.pdf) - Appendix A: Limitations for ES 2.0 - pp. 110

[image: Specification Excerpt]

Many implementations exceed these requirements, but understand that fragment shaders are more restrictive than vertex shaders. If you could edit your question to include the ***full*** fragment shader, I might be able to offer you an alternate solution.

One solution might be to use a 1D texture lookup instead of array. Technically, texture lookups that use non-const coordinates are dependent lookups, which can be significantly slower. However, texture lookups do overcome limitations of array indexing in GLSL ES.

Comment: @Skorpius: Ultimately after seeing your shader, I think storing this array as a 1D texture and using a texture lookup instead of array indexing is going to be your best bet. If this were a vertex shader, it would be so much simpler to achieve what you are trying to do...

Comment: This answer is indeed quite informative, but as a beginner with WebGL (and OpenGL) I'd like to get a pointer as how to actually implement the solution...